# Jackson serialization ignores '@JsonTypeInfo' and '@JsonIgnore' for Iterator classes?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I've recently upgraded from Jackson 2.9.10 to 2.10.0 and notice a change in how Iterator classes are serialized.

Given the test below, the output with 2.9.10 (with handling of JsonTypeInfo and JsonIgnore) is

{"@class":"IteratorTest"}

but with 2.10.0, JsontTypeInfo and JsonIgnore are not processed, and the output is

["IteratorTest",["one","two"]]

Is the new serialization behavior correct?  Is there a workaround to get the old behavior?

```java
// Test class
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class", visible=true)
public class IteratorTest<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    @JsonIgnore 
    private Iterator<T> iterData;
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    IteratorTest(Iterator<T> iterData) { this.iterData = iterData; }

    @Override 
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterData.hasNext();
    }
    @Override
    public T next() {
        return iterData.next();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("one");
        strings.add("two");

        IteratorTest<String> it = new IteratorTest<>(strings.iterator());

        System.out.println("-- serializing --");
        String s = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(it);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
// end of Test class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, debugging it, with version 2.9.10 you get a `BeanSerializer`, with version 2.10.0 you get a `IteratorSerializer`.

In version 2.10.0, you get the `IteratorSerializer` when your class does not have any properties (`BeanSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAddonType`). In version 2.9.10, you get a `BeanSerializer` from `builder.createDummy()`.

Fix:

- Use a custom serializer
- maybe change the handling of Iterator-Classes for your OM
- Use an existing property, s.t. a `BeanSerializer` is created (this would give you a different json):

  ```
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "myClass")
  class IteratorTest<T> implements Iterator<T> {

      private String myClass = IteratorTest.class.getSimpleName();

      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks sfiss!  I'll instead adopt the new behavior of the IteratorSerializer being used in 2.10.0.